# CMD Copy seeing mutiple files where there is one

Tags: windows, macos, batch-file, cmd

I've been using the same batch script to copy files for the past few years but today something strange is happening. I therefore have tried running a single line of the batch script straight form the CMD.

When I open the Command Prompt and enter the following:

```
copy W:\\3EX_Product_Large\9174.jpg O:\\Catalogue\Images\ImageRequests\Test.jpg
```

Instead of it copying the image, it returns the following:

> ```
> Overwrite O:\\Catalogue\Images\ImageRequests\Test.jpg? (Yes/No/All):
> ```

If I enter `Yes` it copies 271 files.

All well and good if there was:

1. 271 files in the source location with the name `9174.jpg`,
2. a file in the destination called `Test.jpg`.

But there isn't.

I have recently upgraded to Windows 10 and the source location is a Mac server running the latest version of OSX.10.9.5 and the relevant server software. The destination location is on a Windows Server running Windows 12 Server.

Incidentally, copying files across the Windows server runs OK.

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: Hard to tell how a `copy` command line with a single source file can create 271 copies when you do not show us the batch script where it is used in...

Comment: please try `where copy`. If it doesn't say "could not find ..." you found your problem.

Comment: What are the names of the copied files? Are they related to your `W:\\3EX_Product_Large\9174.jpg`?

Comment: In response, the batch file copies images from one place to another and is really simple, it just contains loads of lines similar to the one I typed at the command prompt. This batch file is created overnight and is run by Task Scheduler each night. When I said it copies 271 files, this is what the command line returns when it's done. If you check the destination folder there is of course just the one file called Test2. The purpose of the batch file is to copy images from one location to a web server and rename the images. Pretty sure this is going to be permissions on the various servers.